# Memory leak in custom SQLite wrapper

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsdictionary

In my application I have a connection to an sqlite3 database. I have made a wrapper class, in this wrapper class I have an NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray.

Each time a query is run I `removeAllObjects` from the dictonary and the array in the rapper class (I don't release it). I then add the results from the query to the array and dictionary. The dictionary contains another subdictionaries.

I have a tableViewController, in this class I get data from the database using my rapper class and copy it to my tableviewcontroller variable:

.h

```
     @interface BrandViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate>
{
    FairPriceDatabaseView *FairPriceDB;
    NSArray *brandsIDs;
    NSMutableDictionary *brandsRecords;
    UITableView *tableView;  
}
```

.m

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self loadBrandsIDs];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)dealloc {[brandsRecords release];
    [brandsIDs release];
    [super dealloc];
}
-(NSArray *) loadBrandsIDs
{
    [self loadBrandsDB];

    [brandsIDs release];
    brandsIDs = [[FairPriceDB getBrandIDs]copy];

    [brandsRecords release];
    **brandsRecords = [[FairPriceDB getBrandIDs_NSDictionary]copy];**

    [FairPriceDB release];
    FairPriceDB = nil;
    return brandsIDs;
}
- (FairPriceDatabaseView *) loadBrandsDB {
    if (!FairPriceDB) 
        FairPriceDB = [[FairPriceDatabaseView alloc] initWithFairPriceDatabaseViewFilename:@"b.db"];
    return FairPriceDB;
}
```

When testing I am getting a memory leak in the starred line (`brandsRecords = [[FairPriceDB getBrandIDs_NSDictionary]copy];`)
the memory leak when i change the tableviewcontroller and come back to these tableviewcontrollers happen....

I want to know, am I doing this the correct way? Why is there a leak?

Also, every time I release an `NSMutableDictionary`, do I also need to release the subdictionary which in contained in there or not?

FairPriceDataBaseViewController.h (wrapper class)

```
@interface FairPriceDatabaseView {
    NSMutableArray * idList;
    NSMutableDictionary * recordList;
}
```

FairPriceDataBaseViewController.m (wrapper class)

```
            - (NSArray *) getBrandIDs {
                NSDictionary * row;
                [idList removeAllObjects];  // reset the array
                for (row in [self getQuery:@"SELECT productID,brandName FROM product GROUP BY brandName;"]) 
                    [idList addObject:[row objectForKey:@"productID"]];
                return idList;
            }

            -(NSDictionary *) getBrandIDs_NSDictionary{
                [recordList removeAllObjects];
                [idList removeAllObjects];
                [self getBrandIDs];

                NSNumber * rowid;
                for(rowid in [self idList])
                    [recordList setObject:[self getProductRow:rowid]  forKey:rowid];

                return recordList; 
            }
        - (NSDictionary *) getProductRow: (NSNumber *) rowid {
            self.tableName = @"select * from product where productID = ?";
            return [self getRow:rowid];
        }
        -(FairPriceDatabaseView *) initWithFairPriceDatabaseViewFilename: (NSString *) fn
         {
             if((self = (FairPriceDatabaseView *) [Super initWithDBFilename:fn]))
             {
                    idList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    recordList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
             }
              [self setDefaults];
              return self;
         }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for getAllrecordByRecords?

Comment: So is this even your real code, or just what you remember it to be? As an aside, calling your instance variables `NSArray...` is not good practice. variable names should start with a lower case letter and certainly shouldn't clash with the namespace of framework classes.

Comment: so sry since this is the first time i posted an question on a form, now i add all the real code, also i have a rapper class...

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [objective-C memory management guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/memorymgmt.html). In summary, you have to balance all of your retaining operations (`retain`,`new`,`init`,`copy`) with releases.

Since you are emptying and re-filling your results dictionary and array rather than creating a new one, then copying the results, you will be retaining this object and not releasing it. If you do this more than once then you will be losing the reference to the previous value, so you now have a memory leak.

You need to release the previous value before assigning a new one, or better still create a retained property and add the new value through the synthesized accessor.

Comment: Would you please a give me more detail of this explanation, code or links, thanks

Comment: I have just finished the objective-C memory management guidelines but still, i can not solve this memory leak... the only good point about your answer i can somehow think about my application is that you said " If you do this more than once "... can you guide me give me some example, since when i think i can said when it is upper than one time i change the viewcontroller the meory leak happen..

Comment: @liligago - As a different issue, the use of `if (brandsRecords) [brandsRecords release];` in your above code is a bad practice, and can lead to crashes.  `brandsRecords` will not automatically turn to nil on deallocation, so this conditional is useless and will cause a crash if `brandsRecords` has already been deallocated.

Comment: thank you @BradLarson..i have gotten it after read memory management

Answer (score 0):

`[super dealloc];` should be the last line in a `-dealloc` method.  In your code above, you place it first.

This may cause unexpected behavior, such as not properly releasing the objects that you do after that point, including `brandsRecords`.  This may lead to your leak when the `BrandViewController` is deallocated, because its instance variables may never be released.

Also, as I commented on jrturton's answer, don't do this:

```
if(brandsIDs)
        [brandsIDs release];
```

This is a useless conditional, because if `brandsIDs` has been deallocated, it won't be nil by default (unless you use weak pointers, which you don't here) and your application will crash at this point.  If it is nil, sending a release to nil won't do anything, so why bother having the if statement there?  Just use `[brandsIDs release];`

Comment: I have applied both of these issues but still i have faced with the memory leak....